# How to show that an $N$-dimensional SHO's dynamics symmetry is $SU(N)$?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, symmetry, group-theory, lie-algebra

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetry_in_quantum_mechanics#Conserved_quantities_in_the_Quantum_Harmonic_Oscillator):

> The dynamical symmetry group of the $n$-dimensional quantum harmonic
>   oscillator is the special unitary group $SU(n)$. As an example, the
>   number of infinitesimal generators of the corresponding Lie algebras
>   of $SU(2)$ and $SU(3)$ are three and eight respectively. This leads to
>   exactly three and eight independent conserved quantities (other than
>   the Hamiltonian) in these systems. The two dimensional quantum
>   harmonic oscillator has the expected conserved quantities of the
>   Hamiltonian and the angular momentum, but has additional hidden
>   conserved quantities of energy level difference and another form of
>   angular momentum

How can I show that $\mathbf{H} = \hbar \omega \left(\vec{a}^\dagger \vec{a} + \frac{N}{2}\right)$ has dynamical symmetry of $SU(N)$?

Which operator/generator do I need to show to commute with $H$?

Comment: I would guess they are things like $a_i^\dagger a_i - a_{i+1}^\dagger a_{i+1}$ and, for $i \neq j$, $a_i^\dagger a_j +a_j^\dagger a_i$ or $\sqrt{-1} (a_i^\dagger a_j - a_j^\dagger a_i)$.

Comment: The answer to several of your recent questions is the [Jordan map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_map). Mastery of its properties resolves any and all questions of this ilk.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let 
$$
\vec b=U\,\vec a\, ,\qquad \vec b^\dagger =\vec a^\dagger U^\dagger
$$
then
$$
\vec b^\dagger \cdot \vec b= \vec a^\dagger U^\dagger U\,\vec a=\vec a^\dagger \vec a \quad \Leftrightarrow \quad U^\dagger U=\hat 1\, ,
$$
which defines $U$ as unitary matrix.

Actually, $SU(N)$ is NOT the dynamical symmetry group of the harmonic oscillator.  This dynamical symmetry group is $Sp(N,\mathbb{R})$ (also called $Sp(2N,\mathbb{R})$ depending on notations).  $U(N)$ (or $SU(N)$) is the simply the symmetry group of the degenerate states of the H.O.

$Sp(N,\mathbb{R})$ is the real symplectic group in $N$ dimensions, with algebra $sp(N,\mathbb{R})$ spanned by $\{a_k^\dagger a_j^\dagger, a_k^\dagger a_j, a_k a_j\}$ with $k,j=1,\ldots, N$.  The subset $\{ a_k^\dagger a_j\}$ spans $u(N)$, making $u(N)$ a subalgebra of $sp(N,\mathbb{R})$.

Note that  $sp(N,\mathbb{R})$ is the dynamical algebra because, in terms of $x$ and $p$, it is spanned by $x_kx_i$, $p_kp_i$ and $x_kp_i+p_kx_i$.  Any observable (such as the kinetic energy) expressed as a polynomial in these basic observables will act within *a single* $sp(N,\mathbb{R})$ irrep.

Thus wiki is not quite correct.  In general the symmetry algebra of $H$ includes all operators that commute with $H$ and close on an algebra, whereas the dynamical algrebra contains $H$ and itssymmetry algebra, but also includes operators that need not commute with $H$ but still close on a (larger) algebra.  For 1d h.o. this would include $x^2$, $p^2$ and $xp+px$ which do not all commute with $H$.  Clearly $H$ is in there as a linear combination of $x^2$ and $p^2$.

Comment: Could you give a definition of the dynamical symmetry group? I also can't find any references that talk about the $Sp(N,\mathbb{R})$ symmetry of the harmonic oscillator. Can you provide any?

Comment: @level1807   1. Moshinsky and Quesne. "Linear canonical transformations and their unitary representations." J.  Math. Phys 12.8 (1971): 1772-1780
 2. Rosensteel  and Rowe. "On the algebraic formulation of collective models III. The symplectic shell model of collective motion." Ann. Phys. (N.Y.) 126.2 (1980): 343-3
 3. Rowe "Microscopic theory of the nuclear collective model." Rep. Prog. Phys 48.10 (1985): 1419.
 4. Chap.3 of Rowe and Wood. Fundamentals of nuclear models: Foundational models. World Scientific 2010.   There is also lost of work in the 60’s and 70s by Barut et al.

Comment: Thank you! How different is the situation in the classical oscillator? Is the dynamical group just $Sp\cap SO=U(N)$?

Comment: I’ve not seen this notion discussed for classical systems but I will ask.

Comment: I came across this wonderful answer while thinking about the question I asked [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/692360/quantum-numbers-which-are-not-eigenvalues-of-the-symmetry-operators). It's pretty cool that both Coulomb and HO in any dimension have residual symmetries. Won't be surprised if Coulomb in 2D ($\log(r)$) has it as well.

Answer (score -2):

It is easy to show that the following operator commutes with the hamiltionian

$$A_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} \hbar \omega (a_i a_j^+ + a_i^+ a_j)$$

Comment: ... showing what exactly?  How are your $A_{ij}$ related to $U(N)$ or $SU(N)$?  $H$ also commutes with the angular momenta, but that doesn't make the symmetry group $SO(N)$.